# presentViewController(UIViewController) not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I wanted to populate my uncontrolled view as presentViewController on my app, but it does not work. I do not want to cover the entire screen. Like on the iPad, it should view at the centre and frame, which is preferred.

Below is my code which covers the entire screen:

```
MyView *testview = [[MyView alloc]init];
testview.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
testview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController: testview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I do not want to push my UIViewController...

Comment: If MyView is just a UIView, you can add it to your view controller by using view.addSubview(testview). If you want to present it modally, i think you should make MyView in a View Controller and present the View Controller instead. Try setting modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext

Comment: it is UIViewController only, i do not want to push as i wanted behind view to be visible...

Comment: Okay.. Try setting testview.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. Or self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. I don't remember which one..

Comment: nope both are not working ... i even tried to set frame or show in centre none is working.... :(

Comment: Okay, have you tried looking at the view hierarchy in the View Hierarchy inspector in xcode, to see if the view controller infact is on top of the other view controller? I think you need to provide more information on the MyView class

Answer (score 1):

You cannot present a View. You must present a controller. for example:

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    MyViewController* vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MY_CTL_ID"];
    [self  presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: hi, i tried your code but it covers entire screen ... i do not wants to cover entire screen ...background controller need to be visible.... similar to iPad app when we do presentViewController.

Comment: also i am presenting UIViewcontroller only..... not view.....it seems it is not possible on iPhone..... as i tried different ways ...it covers entire screen only...:(

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (iOS 9 or later):

```
MyViewController *testVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
testVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
testVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

// Both of these are necessary to make it present as a form sheet on an iPhone/iPod.
testVC.presentationController.delegate = vc;
testVC.presentationController.overrideTraitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:@[[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithUserInterfaceIdiom:UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad]]];

// Set the size if you don't set it elsewhere.
testVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(270, 130);

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, the view controller you are presenting needs implement the  `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>
...
@end

@implementation MyViewController
...
(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    // This makes it use the presentation style that was set when it was presented.
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
...
@end
```